# PHP DateTime::diff produces zeros

Tags: php

This function produces a result of 0:

```
function time_difference($time1, $time2) {
    $dt1 = new DateTime($time1);
    $dt2 = new DateTime($time2);

    $difference = $dt1->diff($dt2);
    var_dump($difference);
}
```

Here is the output of var_dump. Yes, I did verify $time1 and $time2 have valid date/times.

```
object(DateInterval)#7 (15) {
    ["y"]=> int(0)
    ["m"]=> int(0)
    ["d"]=> int(0)
    ["h"]=> int(0)               
    ["i"]=> int(0)
    ["s"]=> int(0)
    ["weekday"]=> int(0)
    ["weekday_behavior"]=> int(0) 
    ["first_last_day_of"]=> int(0)
    ["invert"]=> int(0)
    ["days"]=> int(0)
    ["special_type"]=> int(0)
    ["special_amount"]=> int(0)
    ["have_weekday_relative"]=> int(0) 
    ["have_special_relative"]=> int(0)
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at your question. See how `DateTime` and `datetime` are different colors? Why is that?

Comment: var_dump seems to go wrong on a DateInterval (might depend on PHP version). Try `$difference->format('%y Years, %m Month, %d Days, %H:%i:%s')` instead.

Comment: @Sammitch PHP class names are generally case insensitive. Consistency is good though

Comment: Edited to make them the same. Before I try to get the difference a varDump produces the results for $time1 `object(DateTime)#5 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-11-12 02:32:08" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(14) "America/Denver" }`

Comment: @CBroe There was a bug but it was reported fixed in May 2009 https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45682

Comment: @user2985327 Could you add the code that calls this function to the question?

Comment: @TomFenech thanks for pointing this out. I was passing the same variable to $time1 and $time2. I'm embarrased

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to construct a DateTime object `$dt1` from a DateTime object `$time1`. The [DateTime constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) expects a string. If you're passing DateTime objects in to the function, try this:

```
function time_difference($time1, $time2) {
    $difference = $time1->diff($time2);
    var_dump($difference);
}
```

Comment: I am passing a string to the function `string(19) "2013-11-12 02:32:08"`.  The PHP version is 5.4.20 FYI

Comment: In your comment above you said that `$time1` was a DateTime object

Comment: Sorry. I meant var_dump($dt1); produces `object(DateTime)#5 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-11-12 02:32:08" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(14) "America/Denver" }`

Comment: Just upgraded to PHP 5.4.21 to see if it would make a difference.